# List all git repositories used in a Jenkins build? (Groovy)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Using Groovy and Jenkins Pipeline, is there any method of listing all git repositories and commits checked out using checkout during the course of a build aside from manually parsing the build log? I'm aware that changeSets allows one to see what changes have been made between runs, and that by bookkeeping all of these commits, it is possible to piece together the last known set of commits that were successful in building, but deleting/losing any of these builds would result in an incomplete log and prevent reconstruction. I'd like to know if there's an easier way of obtaining a git configuration for a given build.

Comment: you can do it using git

Comment: Is there a specific command for this, or would I have to do manual bookkeeping using Git and parse the log if I wanted to retrieve this information from a previous run?